# Conversion error for rangeofcharacterfromset from swift 2.3 to swift 3.0

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3, xcode8

I am trying to convert my application from swift 2.3 to swift 3.0. I am facing the following issue. 
I am trying to check whether a range of character set is found or not. Code works fine in swift 2.3 and when converting it to swift 3.0.

[image: I get this error]
Can some one help me out with this issue. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: removing NSString and then commenting out the code to rewrite fixed the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works in playground:

```
let string = String()
let characterSet = CharacterSet()

let stringSet : String = string as String

stringSet.rangeOfCharacter(from: characterSet.inverted, options: String.CompareOptions.caseInsensitive)
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to figure out yourself is to retype the method and use code completion.

[image]

Alternatively read the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsstring/1416898-rangeofcharacter)